# Throw Exception in Bison and catch in main()

Tags: c++, exception, bison

Is it possibile to throw an exception in my .y file and catch it in .l where yyparse() is launched?

Let's write some example code. This is part of my .y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);

typedef enum {  ZERO_DIVISION = 0,
                VAR_DUPLICATE_NAME = 1,
                ...
                GENERAL = 100
             } e_errors;
const char* e_errNames[] = {"ZERO_DIVISION","VAR_DUPLICATE_NAME",...,"GENERAL"};
...

%}

//Symbols
%union
{
    ...
};

%token ...

%start X1

%%

X1:
    BEGIN
    ....
    END
    ;
    {
        ...

        if(myCheck(i)>=0) throw VAR_DUPLICATE_NAME;

        ...
    }
    ;
...

%%
```

And this is how I'm trying to catch the VAR_DUPLICATE_NAME in a wrong way in my .l file:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include "proxydata.tab.h"

void yyerror(char*);
int yyparse(void);

char linebuf[500]; //for output the row in case of syntax error

%}

%option yylineno

blanks          [ \t\n]+
text            [a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+
%%

\n.*            { /* saving the next row in case of syntax error */
                  strncpy(linebuf, yytext+1, sizeof(linebuf)); /* save the next line */
                  yyless(1);      /* give back all but the \n to rescan */
                }

{blanks}        { /* ignore */ };


...             return(...);

{text}          { yylval.str_val=(char*)strdup(yytext);
                  return(IDENTIFIER);
                }

.               return yytext[0];

%%

void yyerror(char *s){ 
    printf("LINE %d: %s at %s in this line:\n%s\n", yylineno, s, yytext, linebuf);
    }

int yywrap (void){
    ;
    }

int main(int num_args, char** args){
    if(num_args != 2) {printf("usage: ./parser filename\n"); exit(0);}
    FILE* file = fopen(args[1],"r");
    if(file == NULL) {printf("couldn't open %s\n",args[1]); exit(0);}
    yyin = file;

    try{
    yyparse();
    }catch(int err){
        printf("ERROR! %s",e_errNames[err]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

In this way, the parser is correctly created, but when I'm giving in input a file which generates an exception, I face the following message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'e_errors' Aborted
>   (core dumped)

I know that before writing `printf("ERROR! %s",e_errNames[err])`, I also should declare. Is this `extern const char* e_errNames[];` enough on the top of the flex file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `yyerror()` or YY_ABORT as the designers intended. Parsers shouldn't throw exceptions unless they malfunction. And you don't want just one error from a parse, you want them all.

NB you're not really catching the error in *flex.* You're catching it in `main()`, which can be anywhere. `yyparse()` calls `yylex()`, not the other way round. Anything thrown by `yyparse()` could be caught in `main()` or whatever else you supply to call it, but not in `yylex()`.

Comment: `yyerror()` and `YYABORT` (no underscore) are very different: the former merely prints a message (typically a syntax error message) the latter let's the parser enter in error mode.  Neither calls the other one, so if you intend to raise an error (e.g., division by 0 detected during parsing) and abort, call `yyerror` with the message of your choice and then `YYABORT`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, if you throw `e_errors`, you need to catch `e_errors`, and not `int`. Even though an `enum` is an integer type, it is not an `int` and `catch` doesn't do conversions.

However, you'd probably be better off using [`YYABORT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Parser-Function), which will give the parser a chance to clean up. (If you're using the C++ skeleton, that might not be necessary, but it should still be effective.) You'll need to stash the error code somewhere, of course.